# Scale Animation of view not matching children

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

i wish to scale an entire view, i can get the scale animation working fine and the view is perfect. However the touch area doesn't match the location of the view.

i have then also set the animation to all the children in the view as well, how ever this mess up the layout and positioning. All UI Elements are absolute as the view is a paper based form. I tried editing the pivot X and Y but when scaling larger the elements overlap.
here is my zoom in and out method, replace the plus wit ha minus for zoom out.

```
if (zoomLevel != 1.75f)
            {
                Animation ani = new ScaleAnimation(zoomLevel, (zoomLevel + 0.25f), zoomLevel, (zoomLevel + 0.25f));
                ani.Duration = 500;
                certLayout.Animation = ani;
                ani.FillEnabled = true;
                ani.FillAfter = true;
                certLayout.StartAnimation(ani);
                zoomLevel = zoomLevel + 0.25f;

            }
```

i tried to add this to the zoom method for each child.

```
            for (int i = 0; i < certLayout.ChildCount; i++)
                {
                    View nextchild = certLayout.GetChildAt(i);
                    nextchild.StartAnimation(ani);
                }
```

Comment: I'm confused, are you scaling the whole view, or do you want to scale the children elements of the view when user 's scale gesture is on one of the children elements?

Comment: @gracefeng-msft sorry for the confusion, i am currently scaling the the parent view and this is causing the childs touch events to be out of position? but visually it looks perfect.